# changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS from the official document and trying to write a temperature calculator that calculates whether the water would boil at a given temperature. ([more info](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)) Although the following code functions as expected, I get the warning

> "proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: TemperatureInput is changing an
>   uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled. Input elements
>   should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled"

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
function BoilingVerdict(props) {
    if (props.temperature >= 100) {
        return <p>The water would boil</p>
    } else {
        return <p>The water would not boil</p>
    }
}

class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        const temperature = this.props.temperature;
        return (
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please enter temperature in {Calculate.scaleNames[this.props.scale]}</legend>
                <input value={temperature} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </fieldset>
        )
    }
}

class Calculate extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            temperature: "",
            scale: "c"
        }
        this.handleCelciusChange = this.handleCelciusChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    }
    static scaleNames = {
        c: "Celcius",
        f: "Fahrenheit"
    }

    static toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
        return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }

    static toFahrenheit(celsius) {
        return (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
    }

    static tryConvert(temp, convert) {
        const input = parseFloat(temp);
        if (Number.isNaN(input)) { return; }
        const output = convert(input);
        const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
        return rounded.toString();
    }

    handleCelciusChange(temperature) {
        this.setState({
            scale: 'c',
            temperature: temperature
        })
    }

    handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
        this.setState({
            scale: 'f',
            temperature: temperature
        })
    }

    render() {
        const scale = this.state.scale;
        const temperature = this.state.temperature;
        const Celcius = scale === 'f' ? Calculate.tryConvert(temperature, Calculate.toCelsius) : temperature;
        const Fahrenheit = scale === "c" ? Calculate.tryConvert(temperature, Calculate.toFahrenheit) : temperature;

        return (
            <div>
                <TemperatureInput scale="c" onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelciusChange} temperature={Celcius} />
                <TemperatureInput scale="f" onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} temperature={Fahrenheit} />
                <BoilingVerdict temperature={Celcius} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculate />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `tryConvert` function.

with you initial state, `temperature` is initiated with empty string (`""`). So when this empty string is given to the `parseFloat` of the `tryConvert` method, it gets transformed into `NaN`. You then fall in the `Number.isNaN` condition and your method returns `undefined`.

Latter on, when you enter a value in a field, then the value changes to a real float and the input switch from `uncontrolled` (`undefined` value) to `controlled` (see this doc for more information on controlled and uncontrolled state https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

You have many ways to fix your code. you can either fix the `tryConvert` to always return a valid number (even if the user enters random strings) or just fix the initial value of the `temperature` attribute of your state.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem with my code! But what I'm still struggling to understand is why is `temperature` `uncontrolled` at first and then later becomes `controlled` when I enter a value? According to the official document, **React component that renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a "controlled component".** I though I have already controlled the `input` element through the expression `value={temperature}`.

Comment: As atomrc said, initially, the temperature value is undefined. When it comes to passing props, passing undefined as a value is basically equivalent to not passing anything at all. Thus, it is uncontrolled until an actual value is passed and not undefined.

Comment: @TLadd Thanks for the clarification. I understand it now.